# how to create a countdown timer in visual studio using datetimepicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, datetimepicker

this may sound stupid for some of you but please bear with me. I am trying to create a windows form application that has 2 datetimepicker controls. They are intended to set a time range (date selection has been disabled). After the user sets the range and hits the confirm button, the program needs to display 'A' till the limit and reached and when the timer expires, display 'B'. 
This is my code right now in the click event of the confirm button

```
int a=0;
TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;            
TimeSpan timer = dateTimePicker2.Value - dateTimePicker1.Value;
MessageBox.Show("Timer set. Device will shutdown in " + timer);
timer = timer + time;            
while (time!=timer)
{
    time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay; ;
    if(a==0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("B");
        a = 1;
    };               
};
if (a == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("A");
    a = 0;
}
```

My logic behind this piece of code was this: First find the difference between the two time ranges. Then add this difference to the current system time and do a while loop to check if that time has reached.If not display B. When the current system time reaches the time, display A. I have spend hours over this and cant get it working. When running this code it just displays B and never A.
I'm new to visual studio and this is my first project.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely to be this test:

```
while (time!=timer)
```

it's highly likely that the current time will never be exactly equal to the second time you've picked. You should change this to:

```
while (time < endTime)
```

With this you'll be able to get rid of your variable `a` and just display "A" once the loop finishes.

Having said all this, `MessageBox.Show` will block the loop until you dismiss it so you really need to find some other way of indicating that you're still in the loop.

Comment: Wow that worked. Thanks. Also would it be possible to do validation on the controls. Like preventing the user from selecting an endTime that has already passed ?

Comment: As for the message box, it wouldn't be in the final code. I am using a RF device with an arduino board. Instead of displaying B, a code will be send to shutdown the arduino board and instead of A, turn the device on.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to do validation on the controls. How you do that depends on whether you're using WPF or WinForms amongst other things. Ask a new question if you're struggling with that.